# how can I handle the error with ForkJoin RXJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

everyone .

I would like to know where the observable fails , for example :

If fail in deleteProfOffer or in updateProfOffer, how can I know that when i catch the error.

i've tried this way  :

```
let updateOffer = this._op.updateOfferInfo(offerJob);
        let deleteProfOffer = this._op.deleteProfessionsToOffer(this.offer.id, deleteProf2);
        let updateProfOffer = this._op.setProfessionsToOffer(this.offer.id, updateProf2);

        forkJoin([updateOffer, deleteProfOffer, updateProfOffer]).subscribe(results => {
                this.navCtrl.pop();

                if (offerJob.type_offer === 'job_offer')
                    this.presentToast(`La oferta de trabajo se ha ha modificado correctamente`);
                else
                    this.presentToast(`La oferta educativa se ha ha modificado correctamente`);
            }, error => {
                if (error[0])
                    alert("ERROR 0");
                if (error[1])
                    alert("ERROR 1");
                if ((error[2]))
                    alert("ERROR 2");

                this.navCtrl.pop();
                console.log(error)
            }
        );
```

Comment: You'll need to chain each source Observable with `catchError` where you can wrap it with whatever you need to find out which source Observable errored.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be:

```
forkjoin(
   callWithErrorHandler(updateOffer),
   callWithErrorHandler(deleteProfOffer),
   callWithErrorHandler(updateProfOffer)
).subscribe(...)


callWithErrorHandler(toObserve: Observable<any>):Observable<any>{
  return toObserve.pipe(
    catchError( error => console.log(error) )
  )
}
```

This wraps your calls and add´s an "Error Handler" (the catchError() part ).

warm regards

Comment: oh sorry, that´s the same anwser @martin mentioned. So the credit´s goes to martin. :-)